Can I install garage door, to hide stuff from view. 25’ H steel roof
I own a mobile home, with a double wide steel covered carport. Ceiling is over 24’H. (Built for a 32’L motorhome, sold). Door does not need to completely cover entrance height, nor be weatherproof. Mostly to hide my ‘stuff’ from passersby. Would prefer remote door entrance, if possible.
Cost? Possible? If not possible, any suggestions to cover entrance while allowing my suv access?

how about a picture or two of the car port.

Should be possible.  The height can always be dropped down with a wall.  You do need to add supports for the tracks, which with a 24ft high ceiling will not be as easy as a normal size garage.  Garage doors on hinges or barn door track might be easier and can be remote control for extra cost.  Costs we do not do.
